# How can I merge ordered chapters in MKVs?

Tags: windows, video, merge, matroska

I've got a lot of videos with the opening and endings cut out from each episode. They use ordered chapters and quite a few players do not play nice with these. I would like to merge them into a file. There is an option called [UnlinkMKV](https://github.com/gnoling/UnlinkMKV) for Linux but I can't see something for Windows. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: define quickly.

Comment: @Sickest I've removed "quickly". The original thought process was "without much user interaction", i.e: automated. Although, answers automated or with user interaction are good, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up developing an interface to do this for myself and porting the script over nearly a year later. You can find details on my blog here: http://vaughanhilts.me/blog/2015/04/30/unlinking-mkvs-on-windows-osx-linux.html

The steps essentially involve:

1. Download and extract UnlinkMKV-GUI
2. Install Strawberry Perl, MKVToolnix
3. Select an input folder, output folder and then hit "Unlink"

Github project: https://github.com/hilts-vaughan/UnlinkMKV-GUI

I hope this helps someone.